# change event doesn't fire when there is only one element in array

Tags: html, typescript, angular6

I am using angular 6 to develop a web app.I have an array of locations and an option list that populate the name of locations.I am using 'onchange' event to get the selected location.My problem is,if there is only one element in locations array the onchange event doesn't fire.can somebody please explain about it.?if there is more than one element,then there is no problem,it perfectly works.
 if there is only element in my array, how can i achieve it?

```
  <div class="form-group w-50">
    <label for="locations" style="font-size: 14px" class="mb-0">Select
      Location:</label>
    <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="loca" (input)="onLocationSelect($event.target.value)">
      <option *ngFor="let locations of locationsArray" value={{locations?.id}}>{{locations?.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

### component.ts:

```
 onLocationSelect(value: string) {
try {
  const tempValue = value 
  this.selectedLocation = tempValue;
  console.log(tempValue)
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}`enter code here`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do it exactly like that. I would recommend setting adding a `[(ngModel)]="selectedLocation"` to your select element. And inside your typescript you could set the default value for the select by doing something like

```js
selectedLocation = locationsArray[0];

 onLocationSelect(value: string) {
 console.log(`location was changed to ${value}`);
}
```

This way the selectedLocation property will always reflect the actual selected value and inside your `onLocationSelect` function you can still execute the logic when it actually changed.